# How to hide elements when visibility: hidden isn't right and display: none doesn't work?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've added some plugins to a WP site I'm working on and I can't get the view correct using `visibility: hidden`. When I add `display: none`, which is what I feel is correct, nothing is hidden and the view stays the same.

**Form with `{hidden: none}`**

[image: form with {hidden: none}]

I'm adding this code to the custom CSS in WordPress to hide some unnecessary text:

```
span.wholesale_price_order_quantity_step {
    visibility:hidden
}
span.wholesale_price_order_quantity {
    visibility:hidden
}
```

I can remove the text **(Min:6, Increments of 6)** by using the code above, but am left with space that I can't get rid of.

**Form with `{visibility: hidden}` but white space**

[image: form with {visibility: hidden} but white space]

How can I get rid of the white space and align the price to the product description?

Comment: Please can you show your html too, but you could try position fixed left:100%;also why doesn't display none work? Have you inspected the element to see if there are any overriding styles?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason "display: none;" isn't working could be due to it already being set somewhere else in your code. Try adding `!important` to the end of it to override that.

Like this:

```
display: none !important;
```